# In maven pom.xml always have to change version of vault plugin

Tags: java, xml, maven, aem

In every `pom.xml` maven project, i always have to change the plugin `content-package-maven-plugin` from version `0.0.20` to `0.0.24` because if i try to make a `mvn clean install` it gives an error.

Why this is happening?
The xml code is the following:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.24</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <username>${crx.username}</username>
                        <password>${crx.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

This is maven info:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T08:57:37-03:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

This is part of the error i'm getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:package (default-package) on project com.pwc.base-content: Execution default-package of goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:package failed: A required class was missing while executing com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20:package: org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    extension>com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.0.20
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin/0.0.20/content-package-maven-plugin-0.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.3/maven-archiver-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.9/plexus-utils-1.4.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/1.8/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer/1.8/animal-sniffer-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/4.0/asm-all-4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/java-boot-classpath-detector/1.8/java-boot-classpath-detector-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.1/maven-reporting-api-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-6/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.2/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/gonzalocalandria/.m2/repository/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.commons.json/2.0.6/org.apache.sling.commons.json-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.slf4j.helpers.MarkerIgnoringBase
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :com.pwc.base-content
```

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: I would assume the version 0.0.20 has a bug as it looks like ?...

Comment: I doesn't because my other coworkers doesn't need to change that `pom.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:  [Maven error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848324/maven-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-helpers-markerignoringba)

It looks like there was a regression in Maven 3.3.3 that caused this issue that was fixed in 3.3.9.  Your choices would be to use Maven 3.2, 3.3.9 or use the 0.0.24 version of the plugin.

Comment: My coworker have maven 3.3.9 and he doesn't have that problem.. i will try to update maven

Comment: This is the root issue.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5787 it does look like  it was fixed in 3.3.9